# How to keep\add\update multiple values in the same filed inside a document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my database]

I need to change the value of Order: 1.1234 to Order: 1.1234,2.1254,... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of multi-value fields in Cloud Firestore. If you want to store multiple values in a single field, you will have to write the encoding/decoding yourself.

That means that you first need to get the current value of the field, append the new order to it, and then write the result back to the database. You'll want to [use a `transaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) for this, to ensure that multiple users aren't overwriting each other's changes.

Comment: Yup, definitely. Just give them those names in the `set` or `update()` call.

Comment: i need the fields to popup dynamically ,not by .set

Comment: As I said: There is no concept of multi-value fields in Cloud Firestore. If you want something like that, you'll have to implement one of the workarounds: either store multiple values in a single field as I suggested, or name your fields consecutively as you suggested yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a field called 'Orders' which is a basic array of order numbers, and then fetch the array when you get the doc() and parse the data.

As an example I would store the orders like so:

```
  [
    { type: 'Order Type 1', number: 1.234 },
    { type: 'Order Type 2', number: 6.745 },
    { type: 'Order Type 3', number: 1.345 },
    { type: 'Order Type 1', number: 4.556 }
  ]
```

With Firestore there is also the functionality to nest another collection in the document labeled orders. Then when making your calls to this collection you would snapshotchanges() and map through the data and fetch the nested observable in the single Firestore call. This way the orders have their own subscription in case they get changed specifically and nothing about the original document has changed. Let me know if you need some examples of how to achieve this.